# Как удалить строку из DataGrid и удалить её из базы данных SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, события, datagrid

На счёт похожих на StackOverflow вопросов. Они действительно похожи, но нигде нет точного ответа на поставленный вопрос, поэтому задаю его.

Есть база данных в которой хранятся данные о студентах.
Есть форма на которой происходят все действия с бд, такие как удаление, добавление, изменение, удаление и поиск. 
У меня возник вопрос с удалением. 
Есть событие SelectionChanged. Которое по клику определяет строку в дата гриде. Так вот как мне используя это событие производить удаление строки как из DataGrid так и из самой бд.

Код С#:

```
    private void removeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // строка подключения к бд. 
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from Students where (не знаю что сюда написать";
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Students");
        da.Fill(dt);
        DeportamentsGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

Код XAML (WPF):

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button FontSize="20" Content="Назад" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="666,371,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Height="39" Click="BackButton"/>
    <DataGrid   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="601" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="DeportamentsGrid" FocusableChanged="DeportamentsGrid_FocusableChanged" SelectionChanged="DeportamentsGrid_SelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Number_Students}" Header="Номер студента" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding First_Name_Students}" Header="Имя" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Mid_Name_Students}" Header="Отчество" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Last_Name_Students}" Header="Фамилия" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Address_Students}" Header="Адрес" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Course_Students}" Header="Курс" Width="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="updateButton" FontSize="20" Content="Обновить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="666,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Height="40" Click="updateButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="removeButton" FontSize="20" Content="Удалить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="666,251,-0.8,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Height="40" Click="removeButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="addButton" FontSize="20" Content="Добавить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="665,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Height="40" Click="addButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="searchButton" FontSize="20" Content="Поиск" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="666,134,-0.8,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Height="40" Click="searchButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="changeButton" FontSize="20" Content="Изменить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="666,193,-0.8,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Height="40"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: Строки из дата грид на форме.]
[image: Меню, при нажатии на кнопку удалить хотелось бы удалить строку]

Как мне реализовать удаление при нажатии на кнопку "Удалить" используя событие SelectionChanged

Comment: Ну вы ведь начали думать сами, не уж то и эту задачу не реализуете? Подумайте логически, что вам нужно для реализации подобного? Наверно `SelectedItem` из `DataGrid`, верно? Ну так там есть такое свойство, берите его и удаляйте при клике.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это понятно, что есть такое свойство, просто я не совсем понимаю как это сделать, в событие клика кнопки удалить, что нужно прописать? 
Просто `datagrid.SelectedItem` ??

Comment: А вы посмотрите что за тип в `SelectedItem` и что у него за свойства есть, нам же вы это не показываете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ https://ibb.co/rpCsLY4 вот какие свойства у него есть
Я думаю нужно как то так `DeportamentsGrid.Items.Remove()`, реализовывать, только что передавать в Remove?

Comment: `DeportamentsGrid.Items.Remove(DeportamentsGrid.SelectedItem);`? Но у вас вопрос про базу, а не про удаление из таблицы. Вы для команды значения найдите. Ну а вообще, у вас довольно примитивный подход, который по сути не уместен в WPF приложение, научитесь делать привязки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private const string _conString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;" +
                                      "Initial Catalog=DatabaseOneTable;" +
                                      "Integrated Security=True;";
    private const string _selectString = "SELECT * FROM People";
    private readonly DataTable _dataTable;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _dataTable = new DataTable();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(_selectString, _conString))
            {
                //читаем данные заполняем данными таблицу
                int countRecords = adp.Fill(_dataTable);
                Trace.WriteLine($"Прочитано {countRecords}");
            }

            _dataGrid.ItemsSource = _dataTable.DefaultView;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        _buttonRemove.Click += ButtonRemove_Click;
    }

    private void ButtonRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = _dataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        if (row == null)
            return;
        //удаляем
        row.Delete();
        try
        {
            //обновляем в БД (команду DELETE строит билдер)
            using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(_selectString, _conString))
            using (var cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adp))
            {
                var deleted = adp.Update(_dataTable);
                Trace.WriteLine($"Удалено {deleted}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Супер) Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: не подскажите ещё пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы после удаления индекс ID, возвращался в нормальное состояние?
Допустим щас: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 а после удаления 10 элемента идет 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11. 
А хотелось бы: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 после удаления 10-го элемента при добавлении новой записи

Comment: Если у вас ID cделано правильно, то этот столбец в таблице БД должен быть первичным ключом с автоинкрементом, следовательно, то что вы просите невозможно сделать, т.к. значение этого столбца задается БД, а не программно. А если это не так, то вам можно просто пробегать в цикле по строкам `_dataTable.Rows` и у столбца `Id` пересчитывать значение после каждой операции удаления. Вы поймите, я написал ответ исходя из того, что вы работаете через `DataTable`, сам я так никогда не делаю. а работаю через создание класса сущности, кот. хранится в таблице БД.

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос если не трудно) Я не много переделал вывод он теперь работает через список, чтобы удобнее было работать с данными, как мне переделать удаление, чтобы оно работало как и прежде

`foreach (DataRow row in _dataTable.Rows)
            {
                StudentsList.Add(new StudentsClass
                {
                    NumberStudents = Convert.ToString(row["Number_Students"]),
                }
                DeportamentsGrid.ItemsSource = StudentsList;
             }`

Comment: Не совсем понимаю что за список. Вы задайте вопрос как положено, а не в комментарии. Покажите интерфейс программы и код.

Comment: Вот вопрос [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128125)